# System.Data.Entity.Core.Entity Command Execution Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, model-view-controller, datareader

The following unhandled user exception is showing when fetching a list.

System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'EE_PlacementCellModel.PlacedCandidateList'. A member of the type, 'DriveDate', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.'

The exception is shown in the last return code:
**Placement.Context.cs**

```
public virtual ObjectResult<PlacedCandidateList> PlacedCandidateList(Nullable<int> mstID, Nullable<int> cmpID)
        {
            var mstIDParameter = mstID.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("MstID", mstID) :
                new ObjectParameter("MstID", typeof(int));

            var cmpIDParameter = cmpID.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("CmpID", cmpID) :
                new ObjectParameter("CmpID", typeof(int));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<PlacedCandidateList>("PlacedCandidateList", mstIDParameter, cmpIDParameter);
        }
```

Other related codes are given below:
***ReportController.cs***

```
public ActionResult PlacedCandidateList(string MstID, string CmpID)
        {
            int driveID = 0;
            int companyID = 0;
            if (MstID != "")
                driveID = Convert.ToInt32(MstID);
            if (CmpID != "")
                companyID = Convert.ToInt32(CmpID);
            ViewBag.Status = Db.Status.ToList();
            var List = Db.PlacedCandidateList(driveID, companyID);
            return Json(List.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult PlacedCandidate()
        {
            ViewBag.Drive = Db.DriveMasters.Where(a => a.Isdeleted == false).ToList();
            ViewBag.Company = Db.Companies.Where(a => a.Isdeleted == false).ToList();
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PlacedCandidate(CandidateList candidate)
        {
            ViewBag.Drive = Db.DriveMasters.Where(a => a.Isdeleted == false).ToList();
            ViewBag.Company = Db.Companies.Where(a => a.Isdeleted == false).ToList();
            if (candidate.CompanyID == null)
                candidate.CompanyID = 0;
            if (candidate.DriveMasterID == null)
                candidate.DriveMasterID=0;
                List<PlacedCandidateList> CSL = new List<PlacedCandidateList>();
                CSL = Db.PlacedCandidateList(candidate.DriveMasterID, candidate.CompanyID).ToList();

                WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: CSL, canPage: false, canSort: false);

                string gridhtml = grid.GetHtml(
                    columns: grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column("SerailNo", "Serail No"),
                    grid.Column("StudentName", "Student Name"),
                    grid.Column("DriveName", "Drive Name"),
                    //grid.Column("DriveDate", "Drive Date"),
                    grid.Column("CompanyName", "Company Name"),
                    grid.Column("PositionName", "Position Name")
                    )).ToString();

                string exportdata = string.Format("<html><head>{0}</head><body>{1}</body></html>", "<style>table {border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border: 1px solid #ddd;} th, td {text-align: left;padding: 8px; width:100px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;} tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2} th {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;}  </style>", gridhtml);

                var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exportdata);
                using (var input = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                {
                    var output = new MemoryStream();
                    var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
                    var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
                    writer.CloseStream = false;
                    document.Open();

                    var xmlworker = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
                    xmlworker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, input, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);


                    document.AddTitle("Placed Candidates");
                    document.AddCreationDate();

                    document.Close();
                    output.Position = 0;
                    return new FileStreamResult(output, "application/pdf");
                }
        }
```

***PlacedCandidateList.cs***

```
/------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace PlacementCell.Models
{
    using System;

    public partial class PlacedCandidateList
    {
        public Nullable<long> SerailNo { get; set; }
        public int CandidatesListID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string PositionName { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public string DriveName { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int StatusID { get; set; }
        public string DriveDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

***PlacedCandidate.cshtml***

```
@model PlacementCell.Models.CandidateList
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Placed Candidate";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("PlacedCandidate", "Report", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", name = "candidate", id = "candidate" }))
{
    <div class="callout bg-gray-light">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1"><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('candidate').submit();"><div class="btn btn-app btn-twitter"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i>Print</div></a></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <section class="content-header">
        <h1>
           Placed Candidates 
            <small>Report</small>
        </h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> Report</a></li>
            <li class="active"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Placed Candidates</li>
        </ol>
    </section>
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-body">
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-horizontal">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6"> Placement Drive</div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DriveMasterID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Drive, "DriveMasterID", "DriveName"), "Select Drive", new { @class = "form-control", @Onchange = " GetVariables();" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6">Company</div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Company, "CompanyID", "CompanyName"), "Select Company", new { @class = "form-control", @Onchange = " GetVariables();" })

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <a href="#" onclick="GetList();" class="btn btn-primary">Find</a>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />All
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Sl.
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Company Name
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Drive Name
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Drive Date
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Position Name
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Student Name
                                </th>
                                <th>

                                </th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="drive">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
}
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function GetList() {
            var MstID = document.getElementById("DriveMasterID").value;
            var CmpID = document.getElementById("CompanyID").value;
            //alert(MstID);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Report/PlacedCandidateList',
                type: "GET",
                data: { MstID: MstID, CmpID: CmpID },
                dataType: "JSON",


                success: function (List) {
                    //alert("ffffg");
                    $("#drive").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                    //alert("ff");
                    var k = 10;
                    var j = 1;
                    $.each(List, function (i, vari) {
                        var Qun = "arr" + k;
                        var ErrorQun = "arre" + k;
                        var chbbx = '<tr id="checkboxes"><td><input type="checkbox" name="CandidatesListID" id=' + k + ' class="checkbox" value=" ' + vari.CandidatesListID + '" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td><td> ' + j + ' </td><td> ' + vari.CompanyName + ' </td><td> ' + vari.DriveName + ' </td><td> ' + vari.DriveDate + '</td><td> ' + vari.PositionName + ' </td><td> ' + vari.StudentName + ' </td><td> ' + vari.Status + '</td></tr>';
                        $("#drive").append(
                            $(chbbx));
                        k++;
                        j++;
                        //alert(place.Place1);
                    }
                    );
                },
                error: function (List) {

                    alert("No Data Found");
                    $("#drive").html("");
                }


            });

        }



    </script>
}
```

Comment: What do you think that error means?